# Tesseract problem on installation during make

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to install tesseract-ocr on Debian 9 with gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516.

I run with the below order, according to this https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Compiling-%E2%80%93-GitInstallation.md

./autogen.sh
./configure
make

Now when I run make I get the following error:

```
root@genius1062:/usr/local/tesseract# make
Making all in .
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/tesseract'
CXX src/api/libtesseract_la-baseapi.lo
In file included from ./src/ccutil/elst.h:24:0,
from ./src/ccstruct/points.h:22,
from ./src/ccstruct/rect.h:22,
from ./src/ccstruct/boxword.h:22,
from src/api/baseapi.cpp:26:
./src/ccutil/serialis.h: In member function ‘bool tesseract::TFile::DeSerialize(std::vector&)’:
./src/ccutil/serialis.h:107:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘constexpr’
} else if ( constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)) {
^~~~~~~~~
./src/ccutil/serialis.h:107:17: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘constexpr’
./src/ccutil/serialis.h:116:15: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’
} else if constexpr (std::is_class_v) {
^~~~~~~~~
./src/ccutil/serialis.h:151:3: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
}
^
./src/ccutil/serialis.h: In member function ‘bool tesseract::TFile::Serialize(const std::vector&)’:
./src/ccutil/serialis.h:166:15: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’
} else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
^~~~~~~~~
./src/ccutil/serialis.h:198:3: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
}
^
In file included from ./src/ccutil/genericvector.h:22:0,
from ./src/ccstruct/fontinfo.h:25,
from ./src/ccstruct/ratngs.h:29,
from ./src/dict/dawg.h:33,
from ./src/dict/dawg_cache.h:23,
from src/api/baseapi.cpp:28:
./src/ccutil/helpers.h: In function ‘bool tesseract::Serialize(FILE*, const std::vector&)’:
./src/ccutil/helpers.h:252:13: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’
} else if constexpr (std::is_class_v) {
^~~~~~~~~
src/api/baseapi.cpp:2380:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
} // namespace tesseract
^
src/api/baseapi.cpp: At global scope:
src/api/baseapi.cpp:2380:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
Makefile:4696: recipe for target 'src/api/libtesseract_la-baseapi.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [src/api/libtesseract_la-baseapi.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/tesseract'
Makefile:7801: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have tried the popst instatllation iinstruction that id supposed to solve this issue but no luck

```
make all-recursive
Making all in ccstruct
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -
I.. -I../ccutil -I../cutil -I../image -I../viewer -I/opt/local/
include -I/usr/local/include/leptonica -g -O2 -MT blobbox.lo -MD -MP -
MF .deps/blobbox.Tpo -c -o blobbox.lo blobbox.cpp
mv -f .deps/blobbox.Tpo .deps/blobbox.Plo
mv: rename .deps/blobbox.Tpo to .deps/blobbox.Plo: No such file or
directory
make[3]: *** [blobbox.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2`enter code here`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your compiler - current tesseract needs a modern compiler supporting c++17.